# Custom smarty function without identifiers?

Tags: smarty

Is it possible to create smarty functions that accept shorthands or, more specifically, variables without identifiers?

I have a function which takes an object and returns a string; I'm currently writing:

`{myFunc source=$object}`

I want to be able to write `{myFunc $object}` without smarty squawking about missing identifiers, but I don't even know where to begin. It's also entirely possible that I'm missing some fundamental fact which makes this impossible. If that's the case, I'd like to know that too.

Comment: What might `myFunc` be used for/do to `$object`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what `myFunc`'s purpose would be, I believe a [modifier plugin](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl) could be what you are looking for. These are great for taking a string and formatting in another way, like taking a timestamp and formatting it in any way wanted.

> Variable modifiers can be applied to
>   variables, custom functions or
>   strings. To apply a modifier, specify
>   the value followed by a | (pipe) and
>   the modifier name. A modifier may
>   accept additional parameters that
>   affect its behavior. These parameters
>   follow the modifier name and are
>   separated by a : (colon). Also, all
>   php-functions can be used as modifiers
>   implicitly (more below) and modifiers
>   can be combined.

[Source](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifiers.tpl)

Then in your template it would look like

```
{$object|myFunc}
```